# Spring Data Mongodb Query Group By

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using Spring with mongodb , i want to build a query to group my documents by title using GROUP BY like SQL , i have 3 documents:

```
{
  _id: 5eeabfda75204e17242d3ff4,
  title: "Review",
  message: "hi this is a review 1",
  created: 2020-06-18T00: 18: 35.608+00: 00,
  _class: "com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.Notifications"
},
{
  _id: 5eeabfda75204e17242d3ff5,
  title: "Review",
  message: "hi this is a review 2",
  created: 2020-06-15T00: 18: 35.608+00: 00,
  _class: "com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.Notifications"
},
{
  _id: 5eeabfda75204e17242d3ff6,
  title: "Reservation",
  message: "hi this is a a reservation",
  created: 2020-06-15T00: 18: 35.608+00: 00,
  _class: "com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.Notifications"
}
```

Expected Result: I want to have my documents grouped by the title  :

```
{
  "Review": [
    {
      _id: 5eeabfda75204e17242d3ff4,
      title: "Review",
      message: "hi this is a review 1",
      created: 2020-06-18T00: 18: 35.608+00: 00,
      _class: "com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.Notifications"
    },
    {
      _id: 5eeabfda75204e17242d3ff5,
      title: "Review",
      message: "hi this is a review 2",
      created: 2020-06-15T00: 18: 35.608+00: 00,
      _class: "com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.Notifications"
    },

  ],
  "Reservation": [
    {
      _id: 5eeabfda75204e17242d3ff6,
      title: "Reservation",
      message: "hi this is a a reservation",
      created: 2020-06-15T00: 18: 35.608+00: 00,
      _class: "com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.Notifications"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post the query which you have tried ?

Comment: You use an aggregation query with the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage to get the result. You need to group by the `title` field and use the `$push` aggregate operator to store the documents into an array.

Comment: it worked but return id as Object : "_id": {
                        "timestamp": 1592442842,
                        "counter": 2965492,
                        "date": "2020-06-18T01:14:02.000+0000",
                        "time": 1592442842000,
                        "timeSecond": 1592442842,
                        "processIdentifier": 5924,
                        "machineIdentifier": 7675982
                    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I managed to get it working :

```
TypedAggregation<Notifications> aggregation = newAggregation(Notifications.class,
                 match(Criteria.where("idUser").is(idUser)),
                 group("title").push("$$ROOT").as("notifications")
            );
        AggregationResults<Notifications> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, Notifications.class);

        return results.getRawResults();
```